# Gravar resultado de uma pesquisa em um json_encode

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando gravar um resultado de um `query` em um `json_encode` e logo após gravar em um campo no meu `BD`, mas estou recebendo um mensagem de erro e não consegui resolver o problema.

O que estou fazendo:

```
$IdUsuario = $rowData['IdUsuario'];

// RECUPERANDO DADOS
$queryResult = array();
$this->GetConnection()->ExecQueryToArray('SELECT * FROM cadUsuario WHERE cadUsuario.IdUsuario = ' . $IdUsuario, $queryResult);

$string = json_encode($queryResult);

// INSERINDO DADOS DO ITEM LOG
$IdUsuario = $this->GetEnvVar('CURRENT_USER_ID');
// INSERINDO DADOS DA TABELA DE LogItens
$this->GetConnection()->ExecSQL('INSERT INTO cadLogItem (IdLog, Operacao, DataHoraOcorrencia, IdUsuario, Instancia) VALUES ('.$IdLog.', "AT", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '.$IdUsuario.', '.$string.' )');
```

E a mensagem de erro é essa:

```
Cannot execute SQL statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[{"0":"26","IdUsuario":"26","1":"carolmerigue@hotmail.com","Email":"carolmerigue' at line 1
```

O campo no BD está no formato `MediumText`.

Comment: Se é uma *string*, não precisa de aspas na SQL?

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss, está com aspas -> '.$string.'

Comment: Essas são apenas para fazer a concatenação. Dentro da SQL não terá aspas. Basta você debugar seu código para entender o problema.

Comment: da um echo na `$string`. E mostre o resultado. Imagino qual é o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive um problema com o mesmo intuito, salvar `json` em um banco de dados, então achei a solução pro meu problema, simples e fácil assim:

```
$string = json_encode(addslashes($queryResult));
```

Por conta das aspas e/ou apóstrofos, a query sempre dava problema, por isso usei [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php) e resolvi o problema, espero que ajude essa dica.

Comment: Perfeito @Wees Smith, obrigado pela excelente dica.